# Как получить уникальные индексы в массиве? (из запроса в SNMP)

Tags: php, snmp

уважаемые гуру!
На PHP пишу запрос на принтер, для отслеживания заданий о печати. Начальный запрос:

```
$xcmJobName=snmp2_real_walk("10.194.219.221", "public", ".1.3.6.1.4.1.253.8.59.6.1");
```

В ответ приходит следующий ответ:

```
array(22) {
  ["SNMPv2-SMI::enterprises.253.8.59.6.1.1.2.151.8.48.48.48.49.52.66.50.69"]=>
  string(2) """"
  ["SNMPv2-SMI::enterprises.253.8.59.6.1.1.2.151.8.48.48.48.49.52.66.51.49"]=>
  string(2) """"
  ["SNMPv2-SMI::enterprises.253.8.59.6.1.1.3.151.8.48.48.48.49.52.66.50.69"]=>
  string(58) "STRING: "8sviridov_aa                             08122909""
  ["SNMPv2-SMI::enterprises.253.8.59.6.1.1.3.151.8.48.48.48.49.52.66.51.49"]=>
  string(2) """"
  ["SNMPv2-SMI::enterprises.253.8.59.6.1.1.4.151.8.48.48.48.49.52.66.50.69"]=>
  string(41) "OID: SNMPv2-SMI::enterprises.253.8.58.2.8"
  ["SNMPv2-SMI::enterprises.253.8.59.6.1.1.4.151.8.48.48.48.49.52.66.51.49"]=>
  string(41) "OID: SNMPv2-SMI::enterprises.253.8.58.2.8"
  ["SNMPv2-SMI::enterprises.253.8.59.6.1.1.5.151.8.48.48.48.49.52.66.50.69"]=>
  string(18) "INTEGER: 268520238"
  ["SNMPv2-SMI::enterprises.253.8.59.6.1.1.5.151.8.48.48.48.49.52.66.51.49"]=>
  string(18) "INTEGER: 268520241"
  ["SNMPv2-SMI::enterprises.253.8.59.6.1.1.6.151.8.48.48.48.49.52.66.50.69"]=>
  string(18) "INTEGER: 285297454"
  ["SNMPv2-SMI::enterprises.253.8.59.6.1.1.6.151.8.48.48.48.49.52.66.51.49"]=>
  string(18) "INTEGER: 285297457"
  ["SNMPv2-SMI::enterprises.253.8.59.6.1.1.7.151.8.48.48.48.49.52.66.50.69"]=>
  string(11) "INTEGER: 38"
  ["SNMPv2-SMI::enterprises.253.8.59.6.1.1.7.151.8.48.48.48.49.52.66.51.49"]=>
  string(10) "INTEGER: 1"
  ["SNMPv2-SMI::enterprises.253.8.59.6.1.1.8.151.8.48.48.48.49.52.66.50.69"]=>
  string(10) "INTEGER: 0"
  ["SNMPv2-SMI::enterprises.253.8.59.6.1.1.8.151.8.48.48.48.49.52.66.51.49"]=>
  string(10) "INTEGER: 0"
  ["SNMPv2-SMI::enterprises.253.8.59.6.1.1.9.151.8.48.48.48.49.52.66.50.69"]=>
  string(11) "INTEGER: 17"
  ["SNMPv2-SMI::enterprises.253.8.59.6.1.1.9.151.8.48.48.48.49.52.66.51.49"]=>
  string(11) "INTEGER: 17"
  ["SNMPv2-SMI::enterprises.253.8.59.6.1.1.10.151.8.48.48.48.49.52.66.50.69"]=>
  string(12) "INTEGER: 256"
  ["SNMPv2-SMI::enterprises.253.8.59.6.1.1.10.151.8.48.48.48.49.52.66.51.49"]=>
  string(11) "INTEGER: 16"
  ["SNMPv2-SMI::enterprises.253.8.59.6.1.1.11.151.8.48.48.48.49.52.66.50.69"]=>
  string(10) "INTEGER: 0"
  ["SNMPv2-SMI::enterprises.253.8.59.6.1.1.11.151.8.48.48.48.49.52.66.51.49"]=>
  string(10) "INTEGER: 0"
  ["SNMPv2-SMI::enterprises.253.8.59.6.1.1.12.151.8.48.48.48.49.52.66.50.69"]=>
  string(10) "INTEGER: 0"
  ["SNMPv2-SMI::enterprises.253.8.59.6.1.1.12.151.8.48.48.48.49.52.66.51.49"]=>
  string(10) "INTEGER: 0"
}
```

Так вот мне необходимо, получить уникальные ключи этих значений из строк:
SNMPv2-SMI::enterprises.253.8.59.6.1.1.**2**.151.8.48.48.48.49.52.66.50.69
SNMPv2-SMI::enterprises.253.8.59.6.1.1.**3**.151.8.48.48.48.49.52.66.51.49
(и далее по списку, подменяя значения 2-3-4-5 и т.д.)

SNMPv2-SMI::enterprises.253.8.59.6.1.1. - это строка постоянная.
Цифры 2-3 и т.д. это количество столбцов массива (я знаю сколько их будет, в некоторых местах 3, в некоторых 5 колонок)
Мне нужно выделить в отдельный массив уникальные значения: **151.8.48.48.48.49.52.66.50.69**, поскольку эти значения динамические, и они изменяются.
Внутри MIB-файла получение индекса невозможно, но если в MIB-браузере делать TableView - то он эти индексы сам выделяет в отдельную колонку
[image: Пример, как отображается в MIB-браузере]
Не могу додуматься, как сделать обработку результата массива, чтобы получить такой же массив индексов.
Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Написал!
Достаточно просто, но если кто-то знает более элегантное решение, прошу написать.

```
$xcmJobName=snmp2_real_walk("10.194.219.221", "public", ".1.3.6.1.4.1.253.8.59.6.1");
//выбираем все только ключи
$all_keys = array_keys($xcmJobName);
$new_array=[];
for ($i=0; $i<count($all_keys); $i++){
    for ($z=0; $z<13; $z++){
        $delete1 = "SNMPv2-SMI::enterprises.253.8.59.6.1.1.".$z.".";
        //удаляем ненужное
        $OID = str_replace($delete1, "", $all_keys[$i]);
    }
    if ($OID!=$all_keys[$i]){
        //если после замены, что-то изменилось, значит добавляем это в новый массив
        array_push($new_array, $OID);       
    }
}
echo "<pre>";
print_r($new_array);
echo "</pre>";
```